# Reverse one of the array's order in an SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in the process of trying to calculate a couple of values The first value I am trying to calculate is this math formula:

**RL = (P<sub>5</sub>*a<sub>1</sub> + P<sub>4</sub>*a<sub>2</sub> + P<sub>3</sub>*a<sub>3</sub> + P<sub>2</sub>*a<sub>4</sub> + P<sub>1</sub>*a<sub>5</sub>)/L**

The Second formula has RL in it but suffers from the same problem.

**M = RL * x - P<sub>5</sub>*(x-a<sub>1</sub>) - P<sub>4</sub>*(x-a<sub>2</sub>) - P<sub>3</sub>*(x-a<sub>3</sub>) - P<sub>2</sub>*(x-a<sub>4</sub>) - P<sub>1</sub>*(x-a<sub>5</sub>)**

When I look at these I see a SUMPRODUCT.

My **P<sub>1</sub>...P<sub>5</sub>** values are layed out in the same order in the range **$C$12:$G$12** Or named range **Axle_P**.

My **a<sub>1</sub>...a<sub>5</sub>** values are layed out in the same order in the array **offset($X$12,$AL$13,0,1,5)** where **X12** is above the first row of **a** values and in the first column of **a** values.  **AL13** holds the row number for the row of interest.

**L** is cell **$D$8**
**x** is cell **$M41**

So I want to use the formula

```
For calculating RL in say cell AA1

=SUMPRODUCT(Axle_P,offset($X$12,$AL$13,0,1,5))/$D$8
OR
=SUMPRODUCT($C$12:$G$12,offset($X$12,$AL$13,0,1,5))/$D$8

For calculating M

=$AA$1*$M41 - SUMPRODUCT($M41-offset($X$12,$AL$13,0,1,5),Axle_P)
OR
=$AA$1*$M41 - SUMPRODUCT($M41-offset($X$12,$AL$13,0,1,5),$C$12:$G$12)
```

The problem is this results in the wrong sequence of:

**(P<sub>1</sub>*a<sub>1</sub> + P<sub>2</sub>*a<sub>2</sub> + P<sub>3</sub>*a<sub>3</sub> + P<sub>4</sub>*a<sub>4</sub> + P<sub>5</sub>*a<sub>5</sub>)**

**How can I revers the order of  either the P array or the A array?**

Now I do plan on combining these eventually into one cell.  when I am done, I plan on copying the formula down through 5 rows.  So essentially 5 different x values with output in 5 cells.

VBA not a valid option and I would prefer to avoid the use of CSE but if it is the only way then I will suffer.

now if you are wondering why I dont change M to

**M = RL * x - (RL *L)**

is that there are some other caveats I will be applying after I get this figured out that will set **P<sub>n-i+1</sub>** to 0 if **a<sub>i</sub>** is less than 0 or greater than **L** and I have that part planned out.  At least I do if this can be done in a SUMPRODCUT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751620/reversing-a-list-in-excel-within-a-formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help of `OFFSET` and an array of column offsets it is possible to reverse a range.

Example:

[image]

The trick is to get each single cell from the range beginning with the end and with offset `{0,-1,-2,-3,-4}`. The `N` function is neccessary because `OFFSET` used with offset arrays leads to `{ref,ref,..., ref}` where `ref` are cell references. This `{ref,ref,..., ref}` will not be evaluated correctly. `N` gets the number from the `ref`.

So your formulas will be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$12:$G$12,N(OFFSET($AB$12,$AL$13,-(COLUMN($C:$G)-COLUMN($C:$C)))))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET($G$12,0,-COLUMN($C:$G)+COLUMN($C:$C))),OFFSET($X$12,$AL$13,0,1,5))
```

Comment: I am off to research this N function...Never used it before.  Then I will need to double check that the formulas you provided work in my spreadsheet.  I did quick math check of your example and yeah, the computer and I agree! 8)  smart computer!

Comment: is the -Column+column generating a integer count since I in my sheet I would not be starting in the first sheet column A?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, instead of N(Offset(...)) I could also use --Offset(...) or 1*Offset(...)? after some testing, apparently not.

Comment: @Forward Ed: `-COLUMN($C:$G)+COLUMN($C:$C)` will calculate the array `{0, -1, -2, -3, -4}` from minus column `C` = -3 plus column `C` = 3 = 0, minus column `D` = -4 plus column `C` = 3 = -1, ... And no, the `N` function cannot be replaced with something other. It is neccessary to get the `N`umber form the cell reference which is calculated by `OFFSET`.

Answer (score -1):

**...meanwhile in Google Sheets:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:E2,QUERY(A3:E3,"select E,D,C,B,A"))
```

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:E2,QUERY({A3:E3},"select Col5,Col4,Col3,Col2,Col1"))
```

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5, TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN( ,
 ARRAYFORMULA(MID(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, B1:B5), 
 LEN(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, B1:B5))-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&
 LEN(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, B1:B5))))+1, 1))), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]