# Iterate circulary column and get sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given two columns c and q,

```
c1 q1
c2 q2
c3 q3
c4 q4
c5 q5
c6 q6
c7 q7
```

How to apply the following formula to get a new column k

```
k1 = c1 * q1 + c2 * q7 + c3 * q6 + c4 * q5 + c5 * q4 + c6 * q3 + c7 * q2 

k2 = c1 * q2 + c2 * q1 + c3 * q7 + c4 * q6 + c5 * q5 + c6 * q4 + c7 * q3 
...
```

The c column values stay in the same position but the q column values start at current position of k and go in reverse circular order.

Comment: Using offset function you can move up or down from a starting position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I think you can just use a fairly basic MOD approach to cycle through the rows in reverse order:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C$1:C$4*INDEX(Q$1:Q$4,N(IF({1},MOD(4+ROW()-ROW(Q$1:Q$4),4)+1))))
```

[image]

Has to be entered as an array formula (in non-O365 versions of Excel) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

In O365,  just

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C$1:C$4*INDEX(Q$1:Q$4,MOD(4+ROW()-ROW(Q$1:Q$4),4)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that needs to be done with a pretty unhandy formula based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751855/10068520) of @Scott Craner and the reference-functionality of `INDEX`.

**Array-Formula: Confirm with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:INDEX($C$1:$C$4,ROW()))*(INDEX($Q$1:INDEX($Q$1:$Q$4,ROW()),N(IF(1,LARGE(ROW($C$1:INDEX($C$1:$C$4,ROW())),ROW($C$1:INDEX($C$1:$C$4,ROW()))))))))+IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($C$1:$C$4,ROW()+1):$C$4)*(INDEX(INDEX($Q$1:$Q$4,ROW()+1):$Q$4,-ROW()+N(IF(1,LARGE(ROW(INDEX($C$1:$C$4,ROW()+1):$C$4),ROW(INDEX($C$1:$C$4,ROW()+1):$C$4)-ROW())))))),0)
```

This is the formula in cell `K1`, which can be pulled downwards. `C` and `Q` are the source columns and `I` and `J` are the sumproduct the upper and the lower results respectivly.

[image]

It is divided in 2 parts. The first part is the sum of the products with reversed `Q` range up till the current row. The second part does the same but for the range from next row on.

It is probably the best to adjust the ranges graphically by pulling on the edges of the colored ranges and pulling the bottom single cells to the last cell of the column.