# Reverse sentence order excel

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-formula, reorderlist

I can only find functions which reverses the words, e.g. Hello -> olleH. However, I need a function which reverses the order of a sentence from last to first. An example could be: "Hello my name is" -> "is name my Hello".

Any suggestions either in VBA or in prebuilt functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Great thanks, the best would be a function which I can control within other functions... – emilk 36 mins ago

Here is an alternative where you can pass the range which has the value.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    MsgBox ReverseString(Range("A1"))
End Sub
    
Private Function ReverseString(rng As Range) As String
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    Dim MyAr As Variant, itm As Variant
    
    MyAr = Split(rng.Value2, " ")
    
    Dim arListCollection As Object
    
    Set arListCollection = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    With arListCollection
        For Each itm In MyAr: .Add itm: Next itm
        .Reverse
        MyAr = .Toarray
    End With
    
    ReverseString = Join(MyAr, " ")
LetsContinue:
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Function
```

If you want to pass a string to the function, for example

```
Sub Sample()
    MsgBox ReverseString("Hello my name is")
End Sub
```

Then the function becomes

```
Private Function ReverseString(s As String) As String
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    Dim MyAr As Variant, itm As Variant
    
    MyAr = Split(s, " ")
    
    Dim arListCollection As Object
    
    Set arListCollection = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    With arListCollection
        For Each itm In MyAr: .Add itm: Next itm
        .Reverse
        MyAr = .Toarray
    End With
    
    ReverseString = Join(MyAr, " ")
LetsContinue:
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Function
```

**Interesting Read:** [Quick Guide to the VBA ArrayList](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/)

Comment: Similar method to what I was thinking.. By why use an extra object? You can just split the string and store in an array - then reverse loop the array and concatenate with a string :)

Comment: Yes you can do it like that as well. I simply like the `.Reverse` method ;)

Comment: Nice use of the ArrayList. Does come in handy at times.

Comment: @JvdV I like your answer better than mine. :D

Comment: This works nice but I cannot really type the function into a cell and get the output in the cell. I'm an R programmer and brand new to excel due to a new job - sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @emilk: `but I cannot really type the function into a cell` yes you can... Paste the first function in a module and then call in excel cell like `=ReverseString(A1)`

Comment: @emilk: Jvdv's answer is a better answer. You did not have to unaccept the answer. I just posted my answer as an alternative.

Comment: Nice, would be worth giving an overview over each ArrayList method +:)

Comment: @T.M.: Done :-)

Answer (score 6):

With Excel 365, you may try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),TEXTJOIN(" ",,SORTBY(X,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X)),-1)))
```

For those without `LET()`, you can try using Excel 2019:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),N(IF(1,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+2-ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))+1))))))
```

Obviously, this would need you to CSE-enter the formula.

---

**EDIT 30-3-2022**:

As per the newest functions in ms365, we could try:

```
=REDUCE("",TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN(" ",,b,a)))
```

Or:

```
=TRIM(REDUCE("",TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),LAMBDA(a,b,b&" "&a)))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. What is this "X"?

Comment: @emilk, a named variable in the [`LET()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot find `LET` function in my O365. So as a workaround I used, `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><d>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</d><d>")&"</d></t>","//d"),ROWS($A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><d>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</d><d>")&"</d></t>","//d"))))-(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><d>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</d><d>")&"</d></t>","//d"))))-1)))` which is not really elegant as your posted formula!

Comment: Does not seem like I have this function in my Excel, unfortunately. I will try this one above.

Comment: But nonetheless, It is an elegant solution :)

Comment: I have deleted my comments. Seems like my microsoft account had multiple office versions which were interferring. All good now :)

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij. It seems you have Excel2019 as does OP if you haven't got `LET()`, `SORTBY()` nor `SEQUENCE()`. Though it's the long way round, your formula does work just fine. I also included a shorter version in my answer if you are interested.

Comment: @emilk, I included an Excel 2019 version in my answer.

Comment: @JvdV I have checked my account and it states that `Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise`. I am suspecting that I can only see these functions once my organization approves the office updates. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote the same post twice :)

Comment: Fingers crossed for quick updates @shrivallabha.redij =)

Comment: Extraordinary. - Could you explain why `N()` formula is necessary? Side note/friendly hint: copying down the vers. 2019 formula seems to reduce the count of tokens with each row deeper. @JvdV

Comment: @T.M. Thanks. The `N()` is no longer needed in O365, but in previous versions you'd use that specifically to return an array of arguments. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47187863/9758194) older thread on the topic. Also, to avoid the reduce of count of tokens, you'd want to use a semi-absolute reference on `ROW(A$1:....` to lock the starting position in case you plan on dragging the formula down.

Answer (score 3):

Try the next simple function, please:

```
Function revWordsInSentance(x As String) As String
  Dim arr, arrRev, i As Long

  arr = Split(x, " "): ReDim arrRev(UBound(arr))
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr): arrRev(i) = arr(UBound(arr) - i): Next i
    
  revWordsInSentance = Join(arrRev, " ")
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next way:

```
Sub testRevWordsInSent()
  MsgBox revWordsInSentance("Hello my name is")
End Sub
```

Comment: Love it for tricky simplicity +:). - fyi might be interested in my late post using the version 365 `Sequence()` function.

Answer (score 1):

**Version 365**

Just for fun an alternative via `Sequence()` function *(version 365)*:

```
Function getReverse2(sentence As String) As String
    If sentence = vbNullString Then Exit Function
    'a) split string into tokens
    Dim tokens:   tokens = Split(sentence)
    'b) build decreasing series
    Dim newOrder: newOrder = Application.Sequence(1, UBound(tokens) + 1, UBound(tokens) + 1, -1)
    'c) rearrange tokens in descending column order
    getReverse2 = Join(Application.Index(tokens, 0, newOrder))
End Function
```

---

**Edit #1 Backwards compatible** // as of 2021-01-14

Not as short as the original approach above, but replying to @FaneDuru 's comment to provide also for a backwards compatible approach:

```
Function getReverse(sentence As String) As String
    If sentence = vbNullString Then Exit Function
    'a) split string into tokens
    Dim tokens:   tokens = Split(sentence)
    'b) build decreasing series
    Dim neworder: neworder = getNewOrder(tokens)         ' << added function call
    'c) rearrange tokens in descending column order
    getReverse = Join(Application.Index(tokens, 0, neworder))
End Function
```

**Help function `getNewOrder()`**

```
Function getNewOrder(arr, Optional ByVal Is365 = False)
    '' //version 365:
    '    getNewOrder = Application.Sequence(1, UBound(tokens) + 1, UBound(tokens) + 1, -1)
    
    '' //prior versions    '
    Dim cols As Long: cols = UBound(arr) + 1: ReDim tmp(1 To cols)
    Dim col As Long:  For col = 1 To cols: tmp(col) = cols - col + 1: Next col
    getNewOrder = tmp
End Function
```

---

**►Edit #2 Backwards compatible - Refined** // as of 2021-11-12

Instead of looping to imitate a reverse `Sequence` *(vers. MS 365)* I found a workaround via evaluation based on column numbers:

```
newOrder = Evaluate(i & "-Column(A:" & Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1) & ")+1")
```

where `Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)` simply gets the column name of the starting element number `i`.

```
Function getReverse2(sentence As String) As String
    If sentence = vbNullString Then Exit Function
    'a) split string into tokens
    Dim tokens:   tokens = Split(sentence)
    Dim i As Long: i = UBound(tokens) + 1     ' number of splitted elements
    'b) build decreasing series
    'Dim newOrder: newOrder = Application.Sequence(1, UBound(tokens) + 1, UBound(tokens) + 1, -1)
    Dim newOrder
    newOrder = Evaluate(i & "-Column(A:" & Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1) & ")+1")
    'c) rearrange tokens in descending column order
    getReverse2 = Join(Application.Index(tokens, 0, newOrder))
End Function
```

Comment: Interesting, in terms of not so usual way... But I all the time try finding solution able to work in all Excel versions (if possible :)). Voted it up.

Comment: @FaneDuru - fyi replied to your comment by an edit juxtaposing two ways to get to the `newOrder` array via vers. 365 or prior versions (btw quite similar to your approach).

Answer (score 0):

If you have later versions of Excel (tested with Office 365) that support `TEXTJOIN()`, `TEXTSPLIT()`, `SEQUENCE()` functions, then below will do the job with no VBA or Lambda.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",FALSE,SORTBY(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ")),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ")),1,COLUMNS(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ")),-1)))
```

Reference/Credit: This answer was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771028/7270462