# Create reversed 1d array

Tags: excel, vba

When using this line in a cell `=COLUMN(A1:D1)`, we got 1 to 4 as 1d array
How can I get the 1d array reversed?

I tried to reverse the reference D1 to A1 but I got the same.

Comment: If you're using excel 365, use [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know about SEQUENCE but the file will be sent to a user with an older version (office 2010)

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751620/reversing-a-list-in-excel-within-a-formula

Comment: Try `=LARGE(COLUMN(A:D),COLUMN(A:D))`.

Comment: `=COLUMNS(A1:D1)+1-COLUMN(A1:D1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mr. Ron for the great solution.

Comment: @YasserKhalil What is the real purpose - to invert the sequence of column numbers, or to get a descending sequence of numbers as an array?

Comment: BTW, why not to use SORT?

Comment: OP mentioned the person who will be using the Excel will be having an Older Version, then `SORT()` Function shall not work.

Comment: @Vitalizzare To use the 1d array in this line `a = Application.Index(a, Evaluate("ROW(1:" & UBound(a) & ")"), Evaluate("LARGE(COLUMN(" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Address & "),COLUMN(" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Address & "))"))` that reorders all columns in range to the reverse order

Comment: @YasserKhalil Sir, though VBasic2008 Sir(Damij Sir) and Ron Sir has given a better solution, I just tried this one, and it reverses the order as well, could you confirm whether this works or not, `=INDEX(A:D,ROW(A1),{4,3,2,1})`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya The purpose is not to create hardcoded 1d array

Comment: @YasserKhalil Sir, alright understood, I am not very familiar with `VBA`, just tried my hands, thank you for letting me, know.

Comment: Seeing your full formula, consider using ActiveSheet.Evaluate vs (just) Evaluate https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/