# Google Sheets SumProduct Reverse

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumproduct

I am trying to take the `sumproduct` (dot product) of two arrays, but I want to reverse the second array. In other words:

```
a_1*b_n + a_2*b_(n-1) +...+a_n*b_1
```

This excel method suggested in the answer here:

[Reverse one of the array's order in an SUMPRODUCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929784/reverse-one-of-the-arrays-order-in-an-sumproduct)

does not work in Google Sheets. Does anyone have another method?

Edit: I should add that I need this to be dynamic in the same way as any other excel formula. meaning when I copy from one cell to another, the sumproduct reversal accounts for the new size and shape of the cell reference changes.

Comment: you want to reverse it horizontaly or verticaly?

Comment: vertically, but I assume the answers are similar.

Comment: example of what i need to do:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7erkcHdQeTDW9GnG8-IWx1pNkgSpq-3OSw3Q8-_Hr4/edit#gid=0

Comment: Ok fixed. Should be public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:B2,sort($C$2:C2,ROW($C$2:C2),false))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:E2,QUERY({A3:E3},"select Col5,Col4,Col3,Col2,Col1"))
```

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:E2,QUERY(A3:E3,"select E,D,C,B,A"))
```

[image]

Comment: I need to be able to copy from one cell to another, so no hard coding cell references.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5, TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN( ,
 ARRAYFORMULA(MID(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, B1:B5), 
 LEN(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, B1:B5))-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&
 LEN(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, B1:B5))))+1, 1))), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Firstly, wow it works perfectly in the example you gave, even if I copy down with the requisite dollar signs. However it doesn't seem to work in the [shared sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7erkcHdQeTDW9GnG8-IWx1pNkgSpq-3OSw3Q8-_Hr4/edit#gid=0). I have very little understanding of the formula, so I am finding it hard to debug

Comment: given the text join, I have the feeling it relates to the variable number of digits in the example array values