# Reverse order of TEXTJOIN Output

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been asked to remove an Excel VBA UDF from an Excel workbook.  This is to allow the workbook to function in a macro-free environment.
The code reverses the order of items in a comma separated string.  The code is extremely simple:

```
Public Function FlipIt(Sin As String) As String
    Dim a, arr

    FlipIt = ""
    arr = Split(Sin, ",")
    For Each a In arr
        FlipIt = a & "," & FlipIt
    Next a
    FlipIt = Left(FlipIt, Len(FlipIt) - 1)
End Function
```

and it is used in the worksheet like:

```
=flipit(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A6))
```

[image]

I wrote the code because I could not figure our how to make `TEXTJOIN()` output in reverse order.

The best I could come up with was to use a helper column.  So in **D1** I enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTA(A:A),"",INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)-ROWS($1:1)+1))
```

and copy downwards.  The use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,D1:D6)
```

I can't believe that a "helper" column is required for something this simple.

Any suggestions??

Comment: I'm 99% sure what the answer is. but I assume `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A6,A5,A4,A3,A2,A1)` is not a viable option?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad  It is viable for short strings, but not long ones.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I had similar question once upon a time on how to reverse the order of an array.  The answer may be applicable here.  Let me see if I can find that question

Comment: are you ok with an array formula

Comment: @ScottCraner .................... **YES** .......................

Comment: was just going to link these two question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751620/reversing-a-list-in-excel-within-a-formula) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929784/reverse-one-of-the-arrays-order-in-an-sumproduct) but I see Scott swoops in with an answer yet again 8)!  Have we figure out how to develope the Scott Signal yet?  Kind of like the bat signal?  @Brucewayne should be all over that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this array formula that creates an array of the names backwards:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(A1:A7,N(IF({1},ROWS(A1:A7)-ROW(A1:A7)+MIN(ROW(A1:A7))))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Once Microsoft releases SEQUENCE to Office 365 it can be shortened to:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A7),,ROWS(A1:A7),-1)))
```

Which can be entered normally with Enter.

Comment: @SolarMike you also forgot the speed of his answers!  You know he is compiling when the answers come quick!

Answer (score 1):

Using the new Dynamic Array functions, this can be done as

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(A1:A6,SORT(ROW(A1:A6),1,-1)*1,1))
```

Or beter yet, if the source is a Spill range

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(A1#,SORT(ROW(A1#),1,-1)*1,1))
```

Comment: Thanks chris ........................ I just got the new functions *(I am using Office 365)*.  I will try them out..................... Thanks again!