# Reverse order of TEXTJOIN range of cells in a row

Tags: google-sheets, textjoin

Formula I am using in Google Sheets:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),true,C2:2)
```

I want to reverse the order those cells are joined so that it is always the furthest right cell first.

Please see image below for example of what I am trying to achieve.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0bZq.png)

I attempted the advice here [Reverse order of TEXTJOIN Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206567/reverse-order-of-textjoin-output) but it did not seem to translate for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Harun's method is correct, but I hope to provide a simpler and more efficient solution.

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),true,SORT(TRANSPOSE(C2:2),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:2)),false))
```

### Explanation

First, the `=COLUMN` formula is used to obtain column numbers for each column that we want to use `=TEXTJOIN` on. In this case, that is the range `C2:C`.

Next, the `=TRANSPOSE` formula works on both `C2:C` and `=COLUMN(C2:C)` to change both from being horizontal arrays to being vertical arrays. This is needed for `=SORT` to function correctly.

The `=SORT` function is then used to order the transposed results based on the transposed row numbers. The third argument of `=SORT` is false because we wish to sort in descending order, from highest column number to lowest.

Finally, everything is combined in the `=TEXTJOIN` function. Each entry returned by `=SORT` is joined together with two line breaks using the `=CHAR` function. The second argument of `=TEXTJOIN` is true because we want to ignore blank entries.

[image: A screenshot showing the results of the formula on an example data set.]

Functions used:

- [=TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)
- [=CHAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en)
- [=SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)
- [=TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)
- [=COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

In ***google-sheet*** try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),1,BYROW(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:2),1,COUNTA(C2:2),-1),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(C2:2,1,x))))
```

[image]