# Excel Formula - Total subscriptions after Nth years based on monthly churn rates

Tags: excel-formula

A business works on a subscription model basis with a expected churn rate (Cancellations) each month during year 1 at 5% & during the following year a churn rate of 2.5% due to the fact these are now established customers (long term).

A new feature or service is launched with a expect increase of subscriptions each month.  I need to calculate how many subscriptions would that be in N years based on a 5% churn rate for the first 12 month & a 2.5% churn rate during year 2.

Below is currently how were are calculating this in excel however this is really in inelegant solution when trying to calculate this for say 5 - 10 year impacts.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF5Rx.png

Are there any accounting formulas or something mathamitcally I can produce to calculate this in a single cell?  Given  I would need to set the given churn rates for each year & length of time.

For ease lets say 95% of the time I would be working on a 3 year model of subscriptions & each year will need its own churn rate.

I thought perhaps something with exp & halving the value might work but have not found anything yet.

Comment: Seeking some clarification. It looks like subscriptions that start in Jan-19 have a churn rate of 0.05 for 12 months, then the churn rate reduces to 0.025. In contrast, subscriptions that start in Dec-19 have the 0.05 churn rate for only **ONE** month after which it reduces to 0.025, and subscriptions starting in Jan-20 immediately have a churn rate of 0.025. Is that what you intended? My intuition is that churn rate should be tied to duration of subscription not absolute calendar date.

Comment: Sorry yes it should have been 5% churn for 12 months than 2.5% for year 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to build the model. I'll make reference to this image:

[image]

First we set up the churn model.

**Row 1**: Since Churn Rates depend on subscription age, Row 1 has the subscription age (in months). This is for reference only and is not used in the calculations.

**Row 2**: Churn Rates.

**Row 3**: Since Churn Rates always enter the calculation as `(1-ChurnRate)`, call that term *(Single-month) Retention Rate*. As an example, in `B3` the formula is `=1-B2`.

**Row 4**: Since the effects of churn are cumulative over multiple months, we define another term *Multi-month Retention Rate* (abbreviated MMRR). In the first month this is set to `1`; in subsequent months this is the product of previous single-month retention rates. So in `C4` the formula is `=B4*B3`; in `C5`, `=C4*C3`, etc.

**Row 5**: The model as described in the Question indicated a fixed rate of new subscriptions = `100/month`. When the subscription rate is fixed, it is convenient to sum up the MMRRs. So in `B5` we have `=B4`; in `C5`, `=B5+C4`; in `D5`, `C5+D4`; etc.

At this point we're essentially done. If you multiply the values in `Row 5` by any fixed rate of new subscriptions (e.g. `100/month` in the original Question) we get the number of subscribers in that month. But what if you want to model where the number of new subscriptions **varies month to month**? Here's how ...

The basic idea is to multiply the monthly subscription rate by its age-appropriate MMRR. Note that `Row 8` has varying numbers of new subscriptions (100, 110, 97) in the first 3 months. To get the total subscriptions in `Mar-19` for example, we need to

1. multiply the `100` (`Jan-19`) subscriptions (that have a 2 month age) by the MMRR for a 2-month old subscription (`0.9025`),
2. multiply the `110` (`Feb-19`) subscriptions (that have a 1 month age) by the MMRR for a 1-month old subscription (`0.95`),
3. multiply the `97` (`Mar-19`) subscriptions (that have a 0 month age) by the MMRR for a 0-month old subscription (`1`), and
4. add those three products together.

This could be calculated on the worksheet by entering in `D9` the formula `=B8*D4+C8*C4+D8*B4`. This type of calculation (sum up the pair-wise products of two arrays) is often done with Excel's `SUMPRODUCT` function. Here we need to take one of the arrays in reverse order, which is not directly supported by Excel. You *could* enter new subscriptions in reverse order, but that's an ugly kludge. Fortunately, it is do-able with a combination of the `OFFSET()`, `COLUMN()` and `N()` worksheet functions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929784/reverse-one-of-the-arrays-order-in-an-sumproduct) for details). The required formula for `B9` is

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B4:B4,N(OFFSET(B8,0,-(COLUMN($B8:B8)-COLUMN($B8)),1,1)))
```

This can then be copy/pasted into the rest of row 9.

This model approach is pretty flexible: the churn rates (row 2) and subscription rates (row 8) can both be varied month to month; the total number of retained monthly subscriptions is calculated automatically.